# Create an automatically numbered list in Markdown format

Tags: markdown, editor.md

What is the best way to create a numbered list in Markdown format? I currently have to manually enter the number I want to appear, but if I add items, I have to renumber them all.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

That should happen automatically (at least in SO flavored MD):

1. test 1
2. test 2

The code I used it:

```
1. test 1
1. test 2
```

The same works for GitHub flavored MD: https://gist.github.com/3489721

You can test it here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: Got it, it doesn't work in vanilla Markdown, but most variants support this.

Comment: That's strange because the official markdown also support numbered lists: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list

Comment: It looks like you're right, I asked this so long ago I don't remember what implementation I was using. I have since been using Pandoc and Github-flavored Markdown and have not had this issue.

Comment: Visual Studio Code supports this feature.

Comment: this works, but Rmarkdown is very, very sensitive to indenting of elements in lists or code chunks between elements of auto-numbered lists.
It is also very sensitive to whether or not there are comment lines <!-- --> between the entries in an auto-numbered list

Answer (score 13):

if you type the first one with a one like this `1. lorem` then as long as
the rest have a space after the dot then it should work

```
1. lorem
4. hello
3. blah blah blah
```

you should get this:

1. lorem
2. hello
3. blah blah blah

Comment: if i have a code block in between the numbers reset to 1, anyway i can avoid that?

Comment: never mind i figured out and wrote an answer to this question  itself https://stackoverflow.com/a/75492769/12719767

Answer (score 3):

OP's Question is easy to solve by adding a number with a dot then a space after. eg: `1.`

we can keep use the same `1.`  for all the items so we don't have to number everything manually and even if you remove the second item you don't have to rename all numbers below

1. item one
2. item two
3. item three

---

But I faced a problem while creating a GitHub gist. auto numbering was not working if i have a code block between them.

### Problem if you have a code block in between

1. step one
2. step two

```js
// a sample code block
```

1. step three (this should be `3.` )
2. step four

---

### Simple Solution

in order to solve this you need to add four spaces to indent content between bullet points

1. step one
2. step two

   ```js
   // a sample code block
   ```
3. step three
4. step four

*Note: you can click on the "edit" button below on this answer to see the underlying Markdown code but click on the cancel button instead of save!*

Answer (score -3):

If you need add any comment/description/whatever under an item in the list. Only this option solved my case.

```
<ol>
<li>option 1</li>
Description
<li>option 2</li> 

    // Code example require empty line between and 4 spaces in front of the code line
    Hello World!
<li>option 3</li>
</ol>
```

**Result**:

1. option 1
  Description
2. option 2
  ```
  // Code example require empty line between and 4 spaces in front of the code line
  Hello World!
  ```
3. option 3

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Because the question was not how to make a list in HTML, it was how to make a list in **Markdown** (which can then be converted to HTML but that's not the point).

Comment: just try it in markdown and come back with result)

Comment: Question about how to make **automatically numbered list**. It is not only about add item in the end. It is also about add item in the middle of the list. I see main inconvenience around 'if I insert items in the list'. Can't find another option that can solve it.

Comment: I never said it was "only about add item in the end". I'm saying that your answer is off-topic. Sorry but it looks like you're misunderstanding the question. Did you try [Timely10's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66858660/2227743) for example? It does insert an element in the middle and gets *automatic numbering*, and it's using **Markdown** as asked by OP.

Comment: Timely10's answer works in case if you have only list as it is. Try to add any comment/description/whatever under an item in the list.

Comment: I tried, it works. I upvoted you.

Comment: I upvoted this @ilu answer works except for entering a fenced code block.  It does work nicely for adding unnumbered comments between numbered items.  I would have edited answer, but edit queue is full.

Comment: @MikeF Thank you for upvoting me. Added in the answer: code example require empty line in between and 4 spaces in front of the code line.